# Add Shortdescription Content to the Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ive made (with the help of the community) this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
function wtom_show_attributes_title()
{
 global $product;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weingut');
    $abb = $product->get_attribute ('pa_rebsorte');
    $abn = $product->get_attribute ('pa_dac-lage');
    $abm = $product->get_attribute ('pa_jahrgang');

    echo "<h1 class='attribut_header1'>" . __($abv,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h1 class='attribut_header2'>" . __($abb,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2 class='attribut_sub1'>" . __($abn,'woocommerce') . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2 class='attribut_sub2'>" . __($abm,'woocommerce') . "</h2>";
}
```

But now I need to add the Shortdescription Content to that function. Ive tried do add a echo shortdescription.
How do I manage to get the description under the last echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some corrections;
add this code to your functions.php.
The **$post** variable returns the current post (product) information:

```
//I didn't understand why you were using it, I believe it was wrong
//you should pass your function and not the woocommerce function again
//add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bwtom_show_attributes_title', 5 );

function bwtom_show_attributes_title()
{
 global $product, $post;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute ('pa_weingut');
    $abb = $product->get_attribute ('pa_rebsorte');
    $abn = $product->get_attribute ('pa_dac-lage');
    $abm = $product->get_attribute ('pa_jahrgang');

    echo "<h1 class='attribut_header1'>" . __($abv,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h1 class='attribut_header2'>" . __($abb,'woocommerce') . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2 class='attribut_sub1'>" . __($abn,'woocommerce') . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2 class='attribut_sub2'>" . __($abm,'woocommerce') . "</h2>";

    //choose which one is most useful to you
    echo $post->post_content; 
    echo '<br />';
    echo $post->post_excerpt;
    echo '<br />';
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
}
```